# Change 1*140 dataframe to 7*20 dataframe in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I change the data-frame structure in python preferably using pandas?

Currently I have data as indexed and it is 1 column and 140 rows. The data is captured in a way such that every 8th value is in the similar category, so basically I need to change the dimension of my pandas data-frame from 1*140 to 7*20. I also need to assign the column name.

While trying to do same, since my data is in list, I get below error

> ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 140), indices imply (7, 140)

The code used is as below:

```
def convertDF(list_reviewDtls):
df = pd.DataFrame(list_reviewDtls, columns =["Review_URL","Review","Profile_URL","Name","Age","Gender","HomeTown"])
df.to_csv('list.csv')
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I don't know if there's a *proper* way to do it, but you can probably use `numpy.reshape` on your list first: `pd.np.reshape(list_reviewDtls,(7,-1))`. Just make sure your data is not transposed like this.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you posted a sample data frame

Comment: I tried, and getting below error:

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x85 in position 7: ordinal not in range(128) ,  assuming that numpy.reshape will return list

Comment: Sounds like you need to work with unicode.

Comment: @Julien Spronck, please fine the below sample data frame:

Comment: 0,http://www.mouthshut.com/review/HDFC-Life-Insurance-review-npsuqnrlulm
1," Last week I did a policy with hdfc life of 30000 per year for 12years then company will pay me 28000 for next 12 years at the end of 24yrs of my plan I will get a huge amount of 300000. So I am happy this plan lets hope for the best. Dont face any fruad and cheat. I also have a account with hdfc bank. Now lets see wt happens
"
2,http://www.mouthshut.com/arjunsinha80
3,Arjun Singh
4,21
5,Male
6,Kolkata

Comment: @Khris, I am able to save it in 1*140, at this time it did not throw any error

Comment: @Khris, Please find the sample code below , without issues:def convertDF(list_reviewDtls):
    df = pd.DataFrame(list_reviewDtls)
    df.to_csv('list.csv')

Comment: @user1829708 don't add code and errors in comments. If you can make your question more complete, do it in the question itself by [edit]ing it. It helps if you read [ask] first and provide us with a [mcve].

Comment: I also suspect that you have an XY problem. Where is that 140-element list coming from?

Comment: @ Andras Deak - It is coming from website. I am initializing a list and keep on adding relevant items to it while migrating from a page to another.

Comment: Since you expect your data to have structure, you should keep that structure. I mean adding items to the list with `append` instead of `extend`, so that you get a list of lists.

Comment: @ Andras - I keep on adding items using append only to list. But it is just the items so it is taking 1*140, can you provide some example while appending to list so that it get restructured to 7*20? should I append something at the end of every 7th items and at the beginning in a loop?

Comment: Consider `lst=[]; lst.append([1,3,5]); lst.append([2,4,6])`. Then this list contains *two lists*, each with 3 elements. This is equivalent to a shape of `(2,3)`, and not `(1,6)`.